# XML: parsing through nested nodes inside nodes and separating by section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, uitableview

I have the following XML schema i'm trying to iterate through:

```
<routes>
     <route>
          <group>Group Name - Will be iPhone section name</group>
          <item>
                <name>Route Name - Will be iphone cell lable</name>
                <url>Route URL - View Did select lable</url>
          </item>
          <item>
                <name>Route Name - Will be iphone cell lable</name>
                <url>Route URL - View Did select lable</url>
          </item>
          <item>
                <name>Route Name - Will be iphone cell lable</name>
                <url>Route URL - View Did select lable</url>
          </item>
          <item>
                <name>Route Name - Will be iphone cell lable</name>
                <url>Route URL - View Did select lable</url>
          </item>
     </route>
   <route>
          <group>Group 2 - Will be iPhone section name</group>
          <item>
                <name>Route Name - Will be iphone cell lable</name>
                <url>Route URL - View Did select lable</url>
          </item>         
          <item>
                <name>Route Name - Will be iphone cell lable</name>
                <url>Route URL - View Did select lable</url>
          </item>
     </route>
</routes>
```

Now most of them have quite a few entries in item - and the Group node will be the section title for the UITableView

Heres how i'm parsing (incorrectly) the XML at the moment:

(Here are the xNode_ declaraions:)

```
static NSString *xNode_route =@"//route";
static NSString *xNode_group =@"group";
static NSString *xNode_item= @"//item";
static NSString *xNode_name = @"name";
static NSString *xNode_url = @"url";
```

Here is the parse code:

```
    CXMLDocument *doc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:dataReply options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *route = [doc nodesForXPath:xNode_route error:nil];//Root node
    for (CXMLElement *item in route) 
    {
        AssessObject *newobj2 = [[AssessObject alloc] init];
        NSArray *arryGroup = [item elementsForName:xNode_group];
        for(CXMLElement *assGroup in arryGroup) 
        {

            newobj2.assGroup = assGroup.stringValue;
            NSLog(@"Assessment Group: %@", assGroup.stringValue);

        }   

        [groupArray addObject:newobj2];


    }

    NSArray *items = [doc nodesForXPath:xNode_item error:nil];//Root node
    for (CXMLElement *item in items) 
    {
        AssessObject *newobj = [[AssessObject alloc] init];
        NSArray *arryName = [item elementsForName:xNode_name];
        for(CXMLElement *assName in arryName) 
        {

            newobj.assName = assName.stringValue;
            NSLog(@"Assessment Name: %@", assName.stringValue);

        }

        NSArray *arryUrl = [item elementsForName:xNode_url];
        for(CXMLElement *assUrl in arryUrl) 
        {

            newobj.assUrl = assUrl.stringValue;
            NSLog(@"Assessment URL: %@", assUrl.stringValue);


        }

            [totalArray addObject:newobj];
    }
}
```

At the moment it's going through all the items x the amount of groups there are, so the loops incorrect somewhere. So if there are 6 groups it's showing a duplicate of the items 6 times.

So that's part one, part two is really how do I separate the arrays in to groups and have the correct items inside them?

Comment: Which parser u r using... i know through NSXMLParser...

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not releasing memory correctly.

You have 6 release statements in the posted code - remove them all.

Then, you need to add two statements:

```
 [release newObj2];
```

for the objects that you explicitly allocate: newObj, and newObj2, right after you add them to the array.

Then, if things don't work, we can talk about the parsing.

Edit:
Ok, let's talk parsing:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *) parseResponseString:(NSString *) responseString {
NSError *error;
CXMLDocument *doc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString: responseString
                                                    options: 0
                                                      error: &error];
if ( error ) {
    NSLog(@"CXMLDocument error: %@", [error description]);
    [doc release];
    return nil;
} 


CXMLElement * el = [doc rootElement];
NSMutableArray *theRoutes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:128];  // adjust to your needs

if ( [[el name] isEqualToString:@"routes"] ) {                       // parameterize these string constants
    for ( CXMLElement *childElement in [el children] ) {
        if ( [[childElement name] isEqualToString:@"route"] ) {
            Route *aRoute = [[Route alloc] init];

            for ( CXMLElement *grandChild in [childElement children] ) {
                if ( [[grandChild name] isEqualToString:@"group"] ) {
                    aRoute.group = [grandChild stringValue];
                } else if ( [[grandChild name] isEqualToString:@"item"] ) {
                    RouteItem *aRouteItem = [[RouteItem alloc] init];

                    for ( CXMLElement *subItem in [grandChild children] ) {
                        if ( [[subItem name] isEqualToString:@"name"] ) {
                            aRouteItem.name = [subItem stringValue];
                        } else if ( [[subItem name] isEqualToString:@"url"] ) {
                            aRouteItem.url = [subItem stringValue];
                        }
                    }

                    if ( aRouteItem && aRouteItem.name && aRouteItem.url ) {
                        [aRoute.routeItems addObject:aRouteItem];
                    }
                    [aRouteItem release];
                }
            }

            if ( aRoute && aRoute.group && aRoute.items.count ) {
                [theRoutes addObject:aRoute];
            }
            [aRoute release];
        }
    }
}
[doc release];
return theRoutes;   // this is your array for your tableview data source.
```

}

Comment: Hey - thanks, i've fixed that and added the release - my parsing is still duplicating though

Comment: @Tom -not sure what's causing the dupes, but to solve problem 2, you need to parse differently.  Rather than treat the XML glob as an opaque database and query it, just parse it from top to bottom, building your data structures as you go.  Create these objects: Route and RouteItem.  Route has a Group member (NSString *) and an array of RouteItems.  RouteItem has a member for Name and Url.  Then feed this array to your tableView, and cellForRowAtIndexPath can pick it apart to display what you want.  See code above (I'm not supposed to write code for you, but your dancing website amused me).